# using constant from template base class

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

The following piece of code doesn't compile under g++ 5.3.1 but compiles under clang 3.7.0.  Which compiler is correct?

```
[hidden] cat c.cpp
template <typename T>
struct Base {
  constexpr static int Align_ = alignof(T);
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T> {
  using Base_ = Base<T>;
  using Base_::Align_;
  alignas(Align_) char buf[1];
};
```

Compile output:

```
[hidden] clang++ -c -std=c++14 c.cpp
[hidden] g++ -c -std=c++14 c.cpp
c.cpp:10:29: error: requested alignment is not an integer constant
   alignas(Align_) char buf[1];
                             ^
[hidden]
[hidden] g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.1 20151207 (Red Hat 5.3.1-2) (GCC)
[hidden]
[hidden] clang++ -v
clang version 3.7.0 (http://llvm.org/git/clang.git 2ddd3734f32e39e793550b282d44fd71736f8d21)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/3.4.6
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/5.3.1
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: .;@m64
```

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug.

Comment: I thought it was https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58109, but the test cases in that bug seem to work with GCC 4.9+...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in GCC because it should work by standard. From the standard draft n4567

> When the alignment-specifier is of the form alignas( ***constant-expression*** ):
>
> (2.1) — the ***constant-expression*** shall be an integral constant expression
>
> (2.2) — if the constant expression does not evaluate to an alignment value (3.11), or evaluates to an extended
>   alignment and the implementation does not support that alignment in the context of the declaration,
>   the program is ill-formed.

In your case you are supplying an integral constant expression.This could fail only if when evaluated the constant expression does not satisfy this

> Alignments are represented as values of the type std::size_t. Valid alignments include only those values
>   returned by an alignof expression for the fundamental types plus an additional implementation-defined set
>   of values, which may be empty. Every alignment value shall be a non-negative integral power of two.
>
> An extended alignment is represented by an alignment greater than alignof(std::max_align_t). It is
>   implementation-defined whether any extended alignments are supported and the contexts in which they
>   are supported (7.6.2). A type having an extended alignment requirement is an over-aligned type. [ Note:
>   every over-aligned type is or contains a class type to which extended alignment applies (possibly through a
>   non-static data member).

Comment: it doesn't fully answer the question.  Based on the sections you quoted, another question arises: should `Align_` be evaluated to a constant? If I substitute `Align_` with `Base_::Align_`, then it compiles under g++.  I suspect g++ thinks `using Base_::Align_` as a declaration of function, so `Align_` is not a constant.  My question is, does standard say anything about 'using Base_::Align_'?  Is it reasonable for g++ to think `using Base_::Align_` as function declaration so thinks it as not constant?