# Error "requested alignment is not an integer constant"

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-alignment

I'm having trouble working around a GCC issue. I'm experiencing it under GCC 4.8, but not 5.1. It looks like its been reported [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56859) and/or [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53017).

The issue surfaces as follows:

```
template <bool B>
struct S
{
    static const int ALIGN = 16;
    __attribute__((aligned(ALIGN))) int x;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    S<true> s1;
    S<false> s2;
    return 0;
}
```

And:

```
$ g++ test.cxx -o test.exe
test.cxx:9:41: error: requested alignment is not an integer constant
     __attribute__((aligned(ALIGN))) int x;
```

Its also kind of important that I keep the `static const` because Clang does not optimize as well as GCC. And C++03 is a requirement as well.

Here's a related question, but it just identifies the bug, and does not offer a workaround: [Using constant from template base class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34376921).

What can I do to work around the issue?

---

Here's the problem compiler, but there are probably others out there considering one of the issues remained for 3 years or so.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

---

The actual use case is a little more involved. If the machine offers SSE2 or above, then alignment is 16. If the machine offers SSE4 or above, then the then alignment is 32. Otherwise, we fall back to natural alignment. So its kind of closer to:

```
template <class W, bool B, unsigned int S>
struct X
{
    static const int ALIGN = (B ? 16 : sizeof(W));
    __attribute__((aligned(ALIGN))) W x[S];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    X<int, true, 10> x1;
    X<long, false, 20> x2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is making the alignment a template parameter a possibility?

Comment: @Yuushi - I ran the test code and it worked, but the template parameter had to be used directly in the `__attribute__`. I think we are going to use Serge's suggestion of essentially mirroring the constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as you say that C++03 support is a requirement, I would step back to a (yes C-ish...) good old define:

```
template <bool B>
struct S
{
    #define CONST_ALIGN 16
    static const int ALIGN = CONST_ALIGN;  // to allow using it later as S<B>.ALIGN
    __attribute__((aligned(CONST_ALIGN))) int x; // this uses a litteral int constant
};
```

Of course the define is not local to the struct and is accessible in all following lines. But after all it does not hurt much (*) and allows old compilers to understand that without repeating a *magic litteral* (here 16).

(*) It only could hide possible typos if in the same file you later use near declarations:

```
static const int CONST_ALIGNER = 12;
...
int b = CONST_ALIGN;  // TYPO should have been CONST_ALIGNER
```

This would lead to a hard to find error